# dynamically set named_scope based on current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, model, controller, named-scope

I keep getting the following error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.size

Based on the current user, when they navigate to a page, I want to limit them to what they can see based on their site. Problem is there is no association between site and user table directly. A contact has_one user (user information is stored in current_user variable). A site has_many contacts. And a site has_many students, where students table has a foreign key of site_id. So there is a link between students and site, so when the current user navigates to students page, they can only see students from same site as them. I can do this by hard coding a number in a named_scope to only display students for the site of the current_user. But different users will belong to different sites so when logged in, the site their associated with will change. That's the problem - to dynamically set that value in a named_scope. This is what I have:

StudentsController

```
def index_scoper
  if current_user.role_id == 8
    super.site_staff_limit while current_user[:site_id]
    # The problem is the user table has no site_id. There is no direct
    # link between the users table and sites table. However, there is
    # a link between users and contacts and then site and contacts and
    # then site and students, where students table has site_id.
  else
    super.with_state.with_site
  end
end
```

Student Model

```
named_scope :site_staff_limit, lambda {|site_id| {:conditions => {:site_id => site_id}}}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

relationship between tables:

users: contact_id
contact: primary key, contactable_id, contactable_type
site: primary key
student: site_id

User model
belongs_to :contact

Contact model
has_one :user
belongs_to :contactable,  :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy

Site model
 has_many :contacts, :as => :contactable
has_many :students

Students model
belongs_to :site

This successfully limits the students by site:
StudentsController
def index_scoper
  if current_user.role_id == 8
    super.site_staff_limit
  else
    super.with_state.with_site
  end
end

Students model
named_scope :site_staff_limit, :conditions => {:site_id => 1}

The problem is different users will belong to different sites, so they can only access student records of the site they belong to. I am having difficulty making that named_scope above dynamic enough to accomplish this.

Comment: Any chance you could format your code a little better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to set up a link between users and sites, with a :through relationship.

Does the code you have provided work?
Is there an error that occurs?

Comment: I have tried dozens of solutions, ranging from many different errors. For example, I tried creating three named_scopes and then referencing them in controller: super.current_user(:contact_id).contacts(:contactable_id, :contactable_type).site_staff_limit(:site_id)
But this gives a no association error.

Comment: Hang on ... it looks like you are trying to call a scope on the controller using "super"?

Comment: yes super contains the students information. It is inherited from a method in the restfulcontroller created in the lib directory, where the students controller inherits from. So super refers to student model.

Comment: So your model is inheriting from the controller?

Comment: StudentsController is inheriting the keyword super from Restful Controller. Then I am applying a named_scope onto super to limit results. Super contains all the records. I want to limit by the site_id of the current_user.

Comment: OK, I am terribly confused and not much help. How can you put a named scope on a controller?

Comment: No, the named_scope is in students model:
  named_scope :contactable, lambda { |current_user|

    case
    when current_user.contact.contactable_id = 1 && current_user.contact.contactable_type = 'site' then
       { :conditions => {:site_id => 1}}
    else
      nil
    end    
  }
I'm trying to filter so only students from same site can view student records.